# Python text files merge from subdirectory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having many text files scattered across many subdirectories. Just want to have compiled single aggregate text file. My requirement is to generate text file that should have directory structure including file name as prefix for each line. TIA

Comment: Your question lacks any sign of research, anything you've done yourself to try and solve the problem, things you've looked at, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import os
root = './'
files = [(path,f) for path,_,file_list in os.walk(root) for f in file_list]
out_file = open('master.txt','w')
for path,f_name in files:
    in_file = open('%s/%s'%(path,f_name), 'r')

    # write out root/path/to/file (space) file_contents
    for line in in_file:
        out_file.write('%s/%s %s'%(path,f_name,line))
    in_file.close()

    # enter new line after each file
    out_file.write('\n')

out_file.close()
```

if you only want some files from the tree rooted at `root` change the third line to

```
# only take .txt files from the directory tree
files = [(path,f) for path,_,file_list in os.walk(root) for f in file_list if f.endswith('.txt')]
```

Comment: Use `os.path` for extracting the extensions and joining paths...

Comment: 10x, @MattiLyra i am getting syntax error for the 'in', in = os.open('%s/%s' % (path, f_name), 'r'). BTW files are in C:\\Tasks\\ folder.

Comment: rather than using in and out use in_file and out_file

Comment: @geo_pythoncl 10x, made some progress, and now got following traceback,  out_f = os.open('master.txt', 'w')
TypeError: an integer is required

Comment: in both cases don't use os.open() use just open()

Comment: just noticed the same thing, use 'open' instead of 'os.open'

Comment: @geo_pythoncl, now code executes without any error :-) . however i noticed two things, 1) path is only displaying for first line of each file., i wish if all the lines can be prepend same way. 2) need to enter new line character between two files when it merges.

Comment: @user1582596 see updated code above

Comment: @Matti Lyra & geo_pythoncl, Thanks a lot for your time and help. this was really a gr8 help.

Comment: @matti-lyra, This solution is working perfectly, but noticed that it also pickups the empty line as task. wondering if there any quick tweak to eliminate blank line.

Comment: @matti-lyra, i was able to manage with this, with open('master.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write("".join(L for L in lines if L.strip()))

Comment: Ok, that doesn't write out the path and name of the file where the line came from

Comment: @matti-lyra i've tried as following, plz help me t correct/enhance ...with open('master.txt', 'r') as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
with open('master.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write("".join(L for L in lines if L.strip())

Comment: @matti-lyra My directory structure and files are now getting bigger. now getting following Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Dropbox\Python\master.py", line 9, in <module>
    for line in in_file:
  File "C:\PYTHON32\LIB\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 972: character maps to <undefined>